# Offset argument does not work correctly in query with custom taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Here are query arguments:

```
$goods_qty = 10;

$arg = array(
  'post_type' => 'goods',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'offset' => $goods_qty * $catalog_index,
  'posts_per_page' => $goods_qty,
  'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'goods_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'sales',
          )
  );
);
```

`$catalog_index` increments with every loaded block of 10 posts. 
So the problem is:

e.g. I have 20 posts. First of them is not under "sales" category. From 2 to 11 all in "sales" category. First time I call PHP with that query everything works perfect. Query picks all posts from 2 to 11 skipping the first one. But on the second iteration query picks the 11th post again. According to my investigation offset argument by some reason works with all posts but apparently not with "sales" posts. But how can it be? It is not logical? How can I have an offset skipping 10 "sales" posts but not posts of all categories instead.

Comment: What happens if you modify it like this `'offset' => ($goods_qty * $catalog_index) + 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$offset = ($catalog_index < 1) ? 0 : $goods_qty * $catalog_index + 1;
...
'offset' => $offset,
```